# Calling function from external JS

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

I am trying to call a function from an external .js file but the console is returning errors and the function is not being called. How do I correct my code and be able to call the function properly.

**Here is the main .html file:**

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="xp.js">
    </script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        window.onload = xyz.makeShape.Circle();
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="xyz" width="600" height="600"></canvas>
</body>
</html>
```

**And here is the .js file:**

```
var xyz = xyz || {};
var canvas = document.getElementById('xyz');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
xyz.makeShape = {
    Circle : function() {
        console.log('working');
    }
}
```

**EDIT**


I am getting 2 errors in the console:

**Error 1**

```
TypeError: canvas is null
window.onload = xyz.makeShape.Circle;
```

**Error 2**

```
TypeError: xyz.makeShape is undefined
window.onload = xyz.makeShape.Circle;
```

Comment: `window.onload = xyz.makeShape.Circle();` should be `window.onload = xyz.makeShape.Circle;`, also you have to wait until the document is loaded before you can get references to DOM elements, here `canvas` and `context` will be undefined.

Comment: *"the console is returning errors"* ... and which errors would that be? I guess you should have a look at http://stackoverflow.com/q/14028959/218196.

Comment: In the future, if you had included the error information in your original question, your question would have been answered in a couple minutes rather than requiring all this back and forth discussion to figure out what you're seeing. Anyway, glad you got it solved eventually.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Change this:

```
window.onload = xyz.makeShape.Circle();
```

to this:

```
window.onload = xyz.makeShape.Circle;
```

`window.onload` needs to be set to a function reference, not to the results of calling a function.

---

You also can't do these two lines from the `<head>` section before the DOM is loaded:

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('xyz');
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
```

You need to execute those after the DOM has been loaded.  There are multiple possible strategies for doing that.  The easiest for what you already have would be to execute them in your onload handler since you know the DOM is already loaded there.  You could also move the script tag that loads your external .js file to the end of the `<body>` section and the DOM will already be ready then when that js file runs.

Comment: @SamarthWahal - come on now.  "It's still not working" tells us absolutely NOTHING about what you see.  Do you expect us to guess?  Help out the people who are trying to help you by describing exactly what's going on and what's in the error console.

Comment: @SamarthWahal - I added another problem to my answer.

Answer (score 0):

You will just need to include the `js` file using the `<script>` tags - either in your header or footer.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/yourjsfile.js"></script>
```

Now you can call functions from that script as if they were in the current file

**Edit**

If you're sure that the file is already included (first make sure you've got the path right) next you need to check your console from errors that may be arising from the included file. The code you've supplied looks right.

Comment: @samarth I've added a small edit. Are you *sure* you've included the right path to the file?

Comment: @jfriend00 common mistake :) - But yes, I see that the OP *thinks* the file has been included, that doesn't mean that the path is right though.

Comment: The path of the file is perfectly correct. I've edited the question and added the errors.

Answer (score 0):

External js:

```
var xyz = xyz || {};
xyz.makeShape = {
    Circle: function () {
        console.log('working');
    }
}
```

Internal js:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var canvas = document.getElementById('xyz');
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    xyz.makeShape.Circle();

}
```

Tested and works