# external JavaScript function not triggered in HTML <script>

Tags: javascript, onload, referenceerror

I know this question has been already addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15721934/calling-function-from-external-js) but that workaround does not work in my case.

I have a function in an external JavaScript that I would like to call immediately after the page is loaded. This is the snippet in the external code to be executed

```
var user_id = "";
var obj = obj || {};

obj.Id = {
    assignId : function(id) {
        console.log(id);
        user_id = id;
        window.alert("ID no:" + user_id);
        return user_id;
    }
}
```

and this is the HTML

```
<script>
obj.Id.assignId("a string");
</script>
```

I also tried this way

```
<script>
window.onload = function() {obj.Id.assignId("a string");}
</script>
```

but `window.onload` is called afterwards in the external file so I think it was overridden as described in [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2810825/javascript-event-window-onload-not-triggered). 
Here is what I get from the console in both previous cases:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: obj is not defined
```

When using this way:

```
window.onload = function() {
    obj.Id.assignId("UA-0001");
```

}

I don't get any error but the function is not triggered though.

What I'm not able to figure out is: if prompting *directly* in the console `obj` I get `Object {Id: Object}` and if prompting `obj.Id.assignId("a string")` I get exactly what I want.

Is there any explanation for this?

Comment: http://plnkr.co/edit/Km81qCnz9ayn0YfG8pgK?p=preview I just copy pasted your code into plunker and it works as expected. External scripts are first, and then execution of the function from external script

Comment: Thanks, but in a real context, e.g. a website, it does not work.

Comment: This is a real context, you must have a racing condition where this function is called before script is loaded, that's why it works when you run from console

Comment: I'm printing some console log and seems that the script is loaded first, and then the function is called later.

Comment: Is it possible that script and the execution of the function have different context/scope?

Comment: After one month I can only say: I don't know. If I use a separate script for this function and then provide the HTML with both links, it works as intended. Sorry for not being able to elaborate more.